# Citrix Receiver 4k DPI scaling issue

Tags: scaling, 4k-resolution, citrix, citrix-receiver

I've set my Windows 10 scaling to 150% on my 2160p display, but Citrix Receiver recognizes a 100% scaling with a 1440p resolution. How can I have the 2160p and 150% scaling even over Citrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay! Got it guys, after many trials.
So,

Citrix Receiver try icon

1. "Advanced configuration" (right mouse click)
2. "Hight DPI"
3. *Set* "No, use native resolution"

Session configuration (from the top drop-down menu)

1. "Preferences"
2. "Display"
3. *Set* "Best resolution"

Now set the Windows scaling to the same value as the local one, disconnect and start a new session.

Comment: Thanks for posting this, you make my new 4k monitor to behave as expected with my work VDI.

Comment: Where do I find the Session configuration? I don't have "Citrix Receiver" but "Citrix Workspace" (v21.x.x.x). I do have the advanced configuration option with HiDPI though.